# tfs unified diff file generation. header line mismatch with patch command

Tags: tfs, diff

I am trying to generate diff file (patch file) and apply this patch to some already deployed folder. I am running the following command to generate diff file:

`tf diff version.asp /format:unified > C:\patch.diff`

It generates something like:

`Comparing local to latest: C:\dev\folder\version.asp
File: version.asp
===================================================================`

**--- version.asp  (local)    2011-06-17 09:18** *text, after file name, should not be here*

**+++ version.asp;958  (server)    2011-09-19 14:27** *the same here*

```
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@
'============================================================
Dim APP_VERSION, APP_BUILD, APP_DATE  
APP_VERSION = 6
-APP_BUILD = 45
+APP_BUILD = 52
%>
\ No newline at end of file
============================================================
```

The problem appears on the line which is bold. The UNIX *patch* application does not recognize file names because these lines should contain only the file name without any additional info.
If I remove text after file name on those lines, *patch* will run successfully.
So my question is: is it possible to generate diff file from tf diff without such information in the header so that it is compatible with *patch*?

There is an alternative like applying regex and replacing such lines but it would be the last attempt to make it working.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

at the end i ended up with `regex` which removes those unnecessary info from the lines, run it with Unix `sed` utility, i got Windows version from `MinGW`.

`sed "s/^\(+++\|---\)\(.*\)\(\.[A-Za-z0-9]\{1,4\}\)\(.*\)$/\1\2\3/" C:\patch.diff > C:\patch.new`

`patch.diff` is malformed file generated from `tfs` and on the output `patch.new` is correct unified diff file and compatible with `patch` utility

**UPDATE2**

after hours of banging head against the wall, i found out that in diff files generated from `tfs` Unicode extended characters are simply escaped or replaced with its closest ASCII representation.

So for example, if code has `ä` letter, in the output diff file it will be replaced by a simple `a` letter.

This makes diff files, generated from `tfs` utility, useless.

This is a bug obviously.

**FYI:**
I am using vs2010 and team foundation server 2010.

Comment: Can you compare the same two files with `diff -u` and then diff the diffs?

Comment: Actually i didn't get your question, sorry

Comment: at the end i ended up with regex which removes those unnecessary info from the lines, run it with Unix command `sed`, i got Windows version from MinGW. `sed "s/^\(+++\|---\)\(.*\)\(\.[A-Za-z0-9]\{1,4\}\)\(.*\)$/\1\2\3/" C:\patch.diff > C:\patch.new` here `patch.diff` is malformed file and on the ouput `patch.new` is correct file and compatible with `patch` utility

Comment: What's your console's locale?

Comment: i couldn't find any setting in cmd, but assuming that cmd uses system locale as a default, my system locale is Russian.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I couldn't figure this out either. TFS creates malformed files with /unified.

I worked around it using a local git install:

```
(shelve change set)
tfpt scorch
git init 
git add .
git commit -a -m "Original"
git checkout -b "New"
(checkout shelf in tfs)
git add . 
git commit -a -m "Change"
git format-patch master
```

:/

Answer (score 1):

If the output from [`tf diff /format:unified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) differs from `diff -u` and is incompatible with `patch`, then this is a bug you should report to Microsoft

As you say, the workaround is to tediously find and replace.